# Can't use Hebrew in the FQL "Where" clause when searching by name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I have a *working* PHP API script, using it for pulling out data with FQL.
However, when I add clauses to the `WHERE` part (Album/Person name, for example), like `name="שלום"`, which include Hebrew, I get empty results.
When using English names, like name="hello" I get full data.

I've double checked it - I should get data because I do have relevant albums with those Hebrew expressions.

I don't really know if it's a FQL or PHP issue, but this just seems like a technical issue.

```
$fql = "SELECT aid,
       owner,
       link
FROM   album
WHERE  owner IN (SELECT uid
                 FROM   USER
                 WHERE  uid IN (SELECT uid2
                                FROM   friend
                                WHERE  uid1 = Me()))
       AND name = 'עברית'  
    ";
$param1 = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
    'callback' => ''
);
$fqlResult1 = $facebook->api($param1);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your PHP Editor working with the correct character encoding?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you quick response :)
I've added "<meta charset="utf-8" />" to the header. should i add something else?

Please don't forget that the problem is with searching the database with FQL query, not by writing down the results or any other text.

Thanks! :)

Comment: @Cranio is talking about your editor, the application you're using to edit your `.php` files, what are you using?

Comment: No, this is ok but works for the page **output**... you must ensure that the text you are actually **editing** when writing the code is in the correct encoding. Many text editors and IDEs have a menu entry for that :)

Comment: Thanks guys,I'm sorry Cranio, i'm old fashioned guy, using the notepad :)

I used the Notepad++ and reencode it as UTF8 and it works.

thanks for your help!!!

solved!

Comment: @Cranio, add it as an answer so OP can accept it and "close" this issue.

Comment: @EtayLiberman I used simple text editors too, but now almost everything is coded in UTF8, it's vital if you use other alphabets, accented characters and so on :)
I've added my comment as an answer for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Adnan suggestion I add my comment as an answer.

So it seemed that the main issue was **character encoding**.

In this particular case, make sure that when you type foreign symbols also your **editor** (yes, the one in which you write the code) is set to the desired encoding.
A good rule would be to make sure you use the very same encoding (I suggest always UTF-8) in:

- your **database** (if you use one - this case is different as it uses FQL), which will affect your queries
- your **html** (via  tags), which will affect your *output*
- your **code** (the very source of the code, a lot of serious text editors for programmers or IDEs have a menu option to set the encoding of the source code), which will assure that che correct byte sequence is used to build strings and queries